# Complex JSON to XML

Tags: c#, json, class, oop

I need to convert JSON to XML, where the JSON is very huge and complex like it contains hundred's of nested tags below is the example 
`

```
{
      "description": {
        "title": "Contiguous U.S., Average Temperature",
        "units": "Degrees Fahrenheit",
        "base_period": "1901-2000"
      },
      "data": {
        "189512": {
          "value": "50.34",
          "anomaly": "-1.68"
        },
        "189612": {
          "value": "51.99",
          "anomaly": "-0.03"
        },
        "189712": {
          "value": "51.56",
          "anomaly": "-0.46"
        }
      }
    }
```

`

The above is just a sample but in reality, it will have more and I want to convert that JSON to XML which is easy and straight forward but in between I want the JSON data to be retrieved or modified or deleted.

I have 2 approaches for that,

1. One option is to convert the entire JSON to plain class and perform CRUD operations on that class.
2. Another option is to convert the JSON to XML and using XPath perform the CRUD operations which is tedious and more time taking, I feel.

I want to know what is the best approach to this problem. Using too many classes is a bad approach?

Comment: Or use JSONPath with Json.NET

Comment: Even that will be tedious and complex when I am handling the large data. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: In any case the "best" approach depends on the actual problem. Any attempt to query raw data without some kind of indexing will be *slow*. Whether you use JSONPath, LINQ or XPath you'll have to scan all elements to find matches. Using HashSet or Dictionary "indexes" will improve performance dramatically

Comment: `Even that will be tedious and complex` don't do it that way then. Store the data in a database, add indexes and query the data. The type of database will depend on the problem and the type of queries you want to perform. Some databases can store time series more efficiently, others use JSON as their native format

Comment: The three options, JSONPath, LINQ or XPath are actually *identical* - deserialize the data and scan it in memory without any indexing support

Comment: To store the data in the DB, I have to convert the JSON data in to model. Creating model is again playing with classes. My  initial question was having too many clasess with few or more properties is the best practice or not? Does it have any memory disadvantages? @Panagiotis Kanavos